# What is dollar sign $ used for internally?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the symbol `$` used for internally?

I do not mean the compound forms `x$388` or `$5` etc., just the `$` by itself.

I am wondering if this is a valid object to use in notation, or what I will break if I do.

Comment: WR use it to charge its customers. Oh ... well, my humour has been criticized before.

Comment: Yes, it's a valid identifier on its own ... and it doesn't seem to be present in any context that's in the path.  `?*\`$` only gives `Compile\`$` (which is protected) in a fresh kernel, but not all symbols are yet loaded after kernel startup.  Regardless, I'd say using it invites trouble.

Comment: Just to clarify, $ can be part of identifier names, just like any alphanumeric character.  But you most likely know this.

Comment: Do you have any reason to use this symbol? Have you depleted the available namespace or so? Are you just fond of $'s?

Comment: @Sjoerd I just like to break things? ;-p  If you look across the top of a U.S. keyboard, the symbols `!@#$%^&*()_-+=` are all in use, except possibly `$`.  It seems reasonable to wonder what purpose it currently is, or could be, put to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 7, symbol `` System`$ ``

used to be already created in a fresh kernel, but not used for anything as far as I know. In version 8, symbol `$` is not pre-created:

```
In[1]:= Context["$"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= Context::notfound: Symbol $ not found. >>

Out[1]= Context["$"]
```

I would agree with [Szabolcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695132/szabolcs) that code using `$` in `System` context might break in future versions, as well as any other code that modifies System symbols.

Comment: Sasha, is it possible for you to get a more definitive answer?  If in version 8 it was removed as a protected symbol, perhaps things are going the other way.  That is, rather than breaking in future versions, safe in future versions?

Answer (score 4):

It is unwise to have user variables that end in an odd number of $ characters (not counting the first character).  x$, y$$$, and $$ are all poor choices for variable names.

This is because appending an odd number of $ to an identifier is a technique called "lexical renaming," which the Mathematica kernel uses to avoid conflicts in variable names when higher-order functions return functions that use the same variable names as their parents.  This technique is used in a variety of scoping constructs, including Function, Module, With, and Rule; here is an example with Function:

```
In[1]:= f = Function[{x, y}, Function[{x}, x+y]]
Out[1]= Function[{x, y}, Function[{x}, x + y]]
In[2]:= f[2,3]
Out[2]= Function[{x$}, x$ + 3]
In[3]:= ?*`x$
Global`x$
Attributes[x$] = {Temporary}
```

In short, appending $ characters is a system-internal renaming mechanism, and identifiers of this form are recognized by Mathematica as "lexically renamed" versions of the $-less forms, with Temporary attribute.  It is not recommended to use variables of this form in your own code.

Mathematica is a term-rewriting language that can behave like a lexically scoped functional language by use of internal rewriting mechanisms such as "lexical renaming."

Comment: As as stated in my question, I am not interested in the compound form that you describe, rather I was wondering about using the `$` symbol itself.

Comment: Are you sure that identifiers ending with `$` are treated by *Mathematica* in a special way? I think that the only difference between "lexically renamed" versions and the $-less forms is that the former get the `Temporary` attribute when *Mathematica* creates them. It is interesting that assigning a value for such symbols even does not break anything: `x$ = 5; f = Function[{x, y}, Function[{x}, x + y]]; f[2, 3][0]`.

Comment: But notice that if you use in inside a scoping construct, you can get accidental name clashes: `In[1]:= f = Function[{x, y}, Function[{x}, x$+y]]`    `Out[1]= Function[{x, y}, Function[{x}, x$ + y]]`    `In[2]:= f[1,2]`    `Out[2]= Function[{x$}, x$ + 2]`    The function parameter x is renamed to x$ which makes it identical to the (supposedly unbound) variable x$ inside the function body.

Comment: Yes, of course it is not desirable to use symbols ending with `$` for the reason of possible name collisions. The primary point of my comment was that *Mathematica* does not recognize such symbols in a special way, they just possibly can be used internally inside scoping constructs. But thank you for the clear example.